# Detecting browser supports SVG stacking

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

SVG stacking is a technique for stuffing multiple SVG images (like icons) into a single file, to enable downloading sets of icons in a single HTTP request.  It's similar to a PNG sprite, except much easier to change/maintain.

The SVG to display is selected using the `#` fragment identifier in the SVG url.  The technique is [**explained here**](http://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/svg-stacking/).

While this technique is arguably on shaky grounds in terms of browser support, (and Chrome doesn't support it all in CSS `background-image`) it works surprisingly well in most browsers if done using an `<img>` tag.  It works in IE9+, Chrome, and Firefox as an `<img>` tag, so a fallback to PNG is only required if you need to support much older browsers like IE8.

Except... Safari is a bit of a problem.  Even though Safari supports SVGs back to version 5 and below, SVG *stacking* just doesn't work in versions < 7.1.  A blank space is displayed where the icon should be.

So, as of now a fallback is probably necessary.  But how can we use feature detection to determine whether we need to fallback to PNG sprites (or at least hide the SVG icon so that a blank space doesn't appear.) ?

The various articles discussing SVG stacks talk about providing fallback for browsers which don't support SVGs.  Essentially, the most common technique is to simply use Modernizer to detect if SVGs are supported, and if not, use PNGs, as [**demonstrated here**](https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/6227428#file-custom_script-js).

But as far as I can see, nobody is discussing the case where a browser DOES support SVGs, but *doesn't* support SVG stacking.  And as far as I know, at least Safari 5 thru 7.0 fall into that category: these browsers support SVGs, but apparently don't support the `:target` pseudo selector that enables SVG stacking to work.

So how can this condition be detected?  Do we have to rely on user agent sniffing here?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

In general, browser cannot answer regarding a feature it doesn't know about. However, some trick came to my mind.

When the image is OK it means that the pixels in it are different, right? And if we see a blank space it means, that all the pixels in it are the same, doesn't matter if they are white, transparent or something else.

So, we can load an image into canvas, take the first pixel and compare the rest with it. If somehing different is found, so the feature is supported, otherwise not. Something like the following code:

```
function isSVGLayersSupported(img)
{
    // create canvas and draw image to it
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // get cancas context and image data
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    // Processing image data
    var data = imageData.data;
    var firstR = data[0];
    var firstG = data[1];
    var firstB = data[2];
    var firstAlpha = data[3];

    for (var i = 4; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        if ((data[i] != firstR) ||
           (data[i+1] != firstG) ||
           (data[i+2] != firstB) ||
           (data[i+3] != firstAlpha))
               return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: A very creative solution, thanks.  Unfortunately it's simply not very reliable.  I tested this solution on a wide range of browsers, and found that many slightly out of date browsers (like iphone5 and firefox 30) correctly display the SVG but nonetheless fail your test.  It seems that for some reason these browers print out all 0,0,0,0 for the RGBA values, even though the stacked SVG image displays correctly - so we get false negatives.  Firefox 30, strangely, has all pixel values equal to the first pixel - yet displays the image correctly.